# Calculating transfer rate and time left while copying a file list

Tags: c#, winforms, system.io.file

I want to get accurate transfer rate and time left while copying a large list of files (also big ones). This should be visualized via a main progress bar and defined labels for speed and time left.

At start of the routine, a backgroundworker iterate through a given directory and builds a dictionary with source and target path.

Mechanism found here: [Calculating Time Remaining on File Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880356/calculating-time-remaining-on-file-copy). (Answer from Steven Liekens)

The problem is, that 100% progress is not never reached, it finished sometime with 96%-98%, but never with 100%. Maybe there is difference to the calculated totalBytes of the (recursive) directory calculation with a different method.

Next point is, that the transfer rate shown is even correct, if it was multiplied with 10 .... So the shown transfer rate with my ssd machine shows 30 MB/s, which is more like 300 MB/s. The shown rate is definitely wrong.

So 2 problems here:
1.) wrong calculation of the progress 
2.) wrong transfer rate calculation (the speed is quite ok)

Can anyone point out why?

```
private void CopyFileList(DoWorkEventArgs eWorker)
    {
        if (fileWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            eWorker.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var totalBytes = GetTotalBytes();
            var currentBytesTransferred = 0L;
            var totalBytesTransferred = 0L;
            var snapshots = new Queue<long>(30);
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100D);
            foreach (var file in FilesToCopy)
            {
                var sourcePath = file.Key;
                var destinationPath = file.Value;
                var sourceFile = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
                //var fileSize = sourceFile.Length;

                timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (fileWorker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        eWorker.Cancel = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Remember only the last 30 snapshots; discard older snapshots
                        if (snapshots.Count == 30)
                        {
                            snapshots.Dequeue();
                        }
                        snapshots.Enqueue(Interlocked.Exchange(ref currentBytesTransferred, 0L));
                        var averageSpeed = snapshots.Average();
                        var bytesLeft = totalBytes - totalBytesTransferred;
                        var speedText = string.Format("{0:#} MB/s", averageSpeed / (1024 * 1024));
                        var timeLeftText = string.Empty;
                        if (averageSpeed > 0)
                        {
                            var timeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(bytesLeft / averageSpeed);
                            var timeLeftRounded = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Round(timeLeft.TotalSeconds));
                            timeLeftText = string.Format("{0}", timeLeftRounded);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            timeLeftText = ("-infinite-");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(speedText);
                        Console.WriteLine("Time Left: " + timeLeftText);

                        fileWorker.ReportProgress((currentBytesTransferred / maximum) * 100));
                    }
                };

                using (var inputStream = sourceFile.OpenRead())
                using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationPath))
                {
                    timer.Start();
                    var buffer = new byte[4096 * 8];
                    var numBytes = default(int);
                    var numBytesMax = buffer.Length;
                    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10D);
                    do
                    {
                        var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                        inputStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, numBytesMax, asyncReadResult =>
                        {
                            numBytes = inputStream.EndRead(asyncReadResult);
                            outputStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, numBytes, asyncWriteResult =>
                            {
                                if (fileWorker.CancellationPending)
                                {
                                    eWorker.Cancel = true;
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    outputStream.EndWrite(asyncWriteResult);
                                    currentBytesTransferred = Interlocked.Add(ref currentBytesTransferred, numBytes);
                                    Results.SizeProgressed = totalBytesTransferred;
                                    totalBytesTransferred = Interlocked.Add(ref totalBytesTransferred, numBytes);
                                    mre.Set();
                                }
                            }, null);
                        }, null);
                        mre.WaitOne(timeout);
                    } while (numBytes != 0);
                    timer.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**An example:**

Copying a directory (21 directories, 228 files, total: 326MB) to a NAS took:
12.4434796 s and reported was a average speed with 2-3 MB/s. But the copying speed was nearly 10 times higher.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: There are no errors, but wrong behavior. This code is working fine and copying the FileList perfectly and with accurate speed - but the collected data or the mechanism for handling multiple files progress is wrong ... Have no glue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like yours. I checked both of your problems and changed the code accordingly. I slightly modified your code to calculate the left time and MB/s speed.

```
private void CopyFileList(DoWorkEventArgs eWorker)
{
   if (fileWorker.CancellationPending)
   {
      eWorker.Cancel = true;
   }
   else
   {
       var totalBytesTransferredInSecond = 0L;
       var totalBytes = GetTotalBytes();
       var currentBytesTransferred = 0L;
       var totalBytesTransferred = 0L;
       var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000D);
       foreach (var file in FilesToCopy)
       {
          var sourcePath = file.Key;
          var destinationPath = file.Value;
          var sourceFile = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
          //var fileSize = sourceFile.Length;

          timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
          {
            if (fileWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
               eWorker.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Remember only the last 30 snapshots; discard older snapshots
                var bytesLeft = totalBytes - totalBytesTransferred;
                var speedText = string.Format("{0:#} MB/s", totalBytesTransferredInSecond / (1024 * 1024));
               var timeLeftText = string.Empty;
               if (totalBytesTransferredInSecond > 0)
               {
                  var timeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(bytesLeft / totalBytesTransferredInSecond);
                  var timeLeftRounded = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Round(timeLeft.TotalSeconds));
                  timeLeftText = string.Format("{0}", timeLeftRounded);
               }
               else
               {
                   timeLeftText = ("-infinite-");
               }
               Console.WriteLine(speedText);
               Console.WriteLine("Time Left: " + timeLeftText);
               totalBytesTransferredInSecond = 0;
           }
       };

       using (var inputStream = sourceFile.OpenRead())
       using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationPath))
       {
          timer.Start();
          var buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
          var numBytes = default(int);
          var numBytesMax = buffer.Length;
          var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10D);
          do
          {
               var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
               inputStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, numBytesMax, asyncReadResult =>
               {
                  numBytes = inputStream.EndRead(asyncReadResult);
                  outputStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, numBytes, asyncWriteResult =>
                  {
                      if (fileWorker.CancellationPending)
                      {
                         eWorker.Cancel = true;
                         return;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                         outputStream.EndWrite(asyncWriteResult);
                         currentBytesTransferred = Interlocked.Add(ref currentBytesTransferred, numBytes);
                         totalBytesTransferredInSecond += currentBytesTransferred;
                         Results.SizeProgressed = totalBytesTransferred;
                         totalBytesTransferred = Interlocked.Add(ref totalBytesTransferred, numBytes);
                         mre.Set();
                         fileWorker.ReportProgress((currentBytesTransferred / maximum) * 100));
                      }
                 }, null);
              }, null);
             mre.WaitOne(timeout);
           } while (numBytes != 0);
           timer.Stop();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Note that I set the timer to 1000 milliseconds. If you want to set the timer to 100 milliseconds, you have to multiply the average speed by 10.

```
totalBytesTransferredInSecond = totalBytesTransferredInSecond * 10;
var speedText = string.Format("{0:#} MB/s", totalBytesTransferredInSecond / (1024 * 1024));
```